# string.split() strange behavior. string.split('.') returning single value with comma separated digits?

Tags: c#, string, split

Here is my code :

```
public static string ClientBasedTime(DateTime? dtInFB, double zoneClient) 
//zoneClient = 5.5
{
    string[] arrTime = zoneClient.ToString().Split('.');
}
```

Piece of code works fine when I try separately, but behave strange in my project. I know it should give me the array of length 2 with value `arrTime[0] = 5` and `arrTime[1] = 5`. But it return the length 1 array with value `arrTime[5,5]`?

Answer (score 6):

You have a problem with localization, you're explicitly splitting with '.', if your machine is in a locale which uses comma instead of dot for decimal separator that's what will happen (ToString will return 5,5 instead of 5.5).

Change your ToString to this:

```
string[] arrTime = zoneClient.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.');
```

In this way .net will always use the dot for decimal separator.